# Angular HttpClient error handling

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I am struggling a bit with how to execute code after an error happened in HttpClient. I would like to know how to set the flag that would turn off a loading spinner when the http called failed. 
I am using RxJs 5.5.2 and Angular 5

```
  private fetch(): Observable<LegalTerm[]> {

    this.isLoading = true;
    return this._http
                .get<LegalTerm[]>(AppSettings.LegalTermUrl, { withCredentials: true })
                .do(() => this.isLoading = false)
                .catch<any, LegalTerm>(this._trace.handleError)
                .do(() => this.isLoading = false)
  }
```

So in the happy path `isLoading = false` works but not sure how to do that after `catch`. It is not working the way the code is now. I am also using a custom error handler as per Angular docs

```
public handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', error: any, result?: T) {
   // do logging etc
   return Observable.of(result as T); // return empty result
}
```

Comment: You should use `HttpInterceptor`.

Comment: `.catch<any, LegalTerm>(this._trace.handleError)` is code that will bite you sooner or later. Fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `finally` operator to change the flag to `false` on complete/error events.

This could be done as follows:

```
import { BehaviorSubject }from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';

@Component()
export class FooComponent {
  private loadingSub$ = new BehaviorSubeject<boolean>(false);
  loading$ = this.loadingSub$.asObservable();

  constructor(private fooService: FooService){
  }

  fetch(){
     this.loadingSub$.next(true);
     this.fooService.getData() 
     // notice that getData() returns a stream that isnt infinite
     .finally(()=>this.loadingSub$.next(false))
     .subscribe(fooData => console.log(fooData)); // error handling not considered
   }  
}

@Injectable()
export class FooService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

   getData(): Observable<any>{
      // error handling not considered
      return this.http.get('foourl');
   }
}
```

More info about the operator can be found [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md)

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';` is what I needed, thanks!